# Flutter Bloc: Return custom constructor object as the state

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have created a model for users details which will be returned after a post request.
Model:

```
class Did {
  String message;
  bool success;
  String id;
  String docHash;
  String pubKey;
  String privKey;
  Object credential;

  Did.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : message = json["message"],
        success = json["success"],
        id = json["id"],
        docHash = json["docHash"],
        pubKey = json["pubKey"],
        privKey = json["privKey"],
        credential = json["credential"];
}
```

I'm calling the post request inside of the repository which gets called from the Bloc. The response of the post request gets parsed with my Model and than returned to the bloc. I now want to set the state to `SubmissionSuccess` with the data of the parsed json. This is the relevant extract of my Bloc which calls the repository:

```
class CreateDidBloc extends Bloc<CreateDidEvent, CreateDidState> {
  final CreateDidRepository? repo;
  CreateDidBloc({this.repo}) : super(CreateDidState());

  @override
  Stream<CreateDidState> mapEventToState(CreateDidEvent event) async* {
    if (event is CreateDidFirstNameChanged) {
      ...
    } else if (event is CreateDidSubmitted) {
      yield state.copyWith(formStatus: FormSubmitting());

      try {
        final res = await repo?.createDid(
            state.firstname,
            state.lastName,
            state.email,
            state.phoneNumber,
            state.dateOfBirth,
            state.sex,
            state.address,
            state.city,
            state.state,
            state.postalCode,
            state.country);
        yield state.copyWith(formStatus: SubmissionSuccess(did: res));
      } catch (e) {
        yield state.copyWith(formStatus: SubmissionFailed(exception: e)); // e is not an exception but an Object ...why
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the repository which creates the post request and returns the json response as a `<Did>` Object. I now want to set this  object as the state of the form submission when the submission is successfull.

```
class CreateDidRepository {
  Dio dio = Dio();
  Future<Did> createDid(
      String firstName,
      String lastName,
      String email,
      String phoneNumber,
      DateTime? dateOfBirth,
      String sex,
      String address,
      String city,
      String state,
      String postalCode,
      String country) async {
    var res = await dio.post("http://did-backend.herokuapp.com/create",
        data: {
          "firstName": firstName.trim(),
          "lastName": lastName.trim(),
          "email": email.trim(),
          "phoneNumber": phoneNumber.trim(),
          "dateOfBirth": dateOfBirth?.toIso8601String(),
          "sex": sex.trim(),
          "address": address.trim(),
          "city": city.trim(),
          "state": state.trim(),
          "postalCode": postalCode.trim(),
          "country": country.trim()
        },
        options: Options(headers: {
          Headers.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
        }));
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      final json = jsonDecode(res.toString());
      print(json);
      return Did.fromJson(json);
    }
    throw "Identity request failed";
  }
}
```

This is my form submission state (blow) but I can't seem to figure out how to set the right type of the `<Did>` object to accept the return value of the repository. My question is, what type do I have to define the did object to?

```
abstract class FormSubmissionStatus {
  const FormSubmissionStatus();
}

class InitialFormStatus extends FormSubmissionStatus {
  const InitialFormStatus();
}

class FormSubmitting extends FormSubmissionStatus {}

class SubmissionSuccess extends FormSubmissionStatus {
  final <Did> did; //error

  SubmissionSuccess({required this.did});
}

class SubmissionFailed extends FormSubmissionStatus {
  final Exception exception;

  SubmissionFailed({required this.exception});
}
```

*Small extra error:* The catch block inside my bloc returns an Object instead of an exception, so I can't assign that to the exception class of the `SubmissionFailed` state. Why does it return and Object?

**Edit:**
Example response of post request.

```
{
    "id": "7hvu33b3QqWzSWVC1hmLMhLiT5PbrT8JH8JFCjPir2Ke",
    "docHash": "FIJ9HZNASYIBIH9QSBSXZBSXQGRARUPGZNMAVOYPUJIXTATLSCNM9WUSLYYZWKGUVBUDLFV9UQYBA9999",
    "pubKey": "GpoGnXs5S2vyMGeSxWoy7gEmyySXyrbTkX7oCcEfyuAR",
    "privKey": "4MKNYQKfeqSXSV7faLSYjAY3SjysnVgHzax9LdfZYVmZ",
    "credential": {
        "@context": "https://www.w3.org/2018/credentials/v1",
        "id": "http://example.edu/credentials/3732",
        "type": [
            "VerifiableCredential",
            "personalInformationCredential"
        ],
        "credentialSubject": {
            "id": "did:iota:7hvu33b3QqWzSWVC1hmLMhLiT5PbrT8JH8JFCjPir2Ke",
            "address": {
                "street": "address",
                "city": "city",
                "state": "state",
                "postalCode": "postalCode",
                "country": "country"
            },
            "dateOfBirth": "dateOfBirth",
            "email": "email",
            "name": {
                "first": "firstName",
                "last": "lastName"
            },
            "phoneNumber": "phoneNumber",
            "sex": "sex"
        },
        "issuer": "did:iota:A5STNhet1zgGbbnZCqniokcAdXbZZ2xcE6QWruQmctEs",
        "issuanceDate": "2021-04-23T22:02:02Z",
        "proof": {
            "type": "MerkleKeySignature2021",
            "verificationMethod": "#key-collection",
            "signatureValue": "3RypuceLDTQt1Anb9WdBj7ayPS91EdiYJ6ELPMChgocm.1117tuDcgbUJddXaLoFqvAh8WWeypGnCTuPCDggJ2cMk6AVyJAjHaaCgSmgaKsGa299TxVBqfypgqbjQx1gExf2kkD9XU8ViYhZRVm9dx5qELnVxcM2H5R5YmL6rLn3RR6SbiNSc7XG.3icG5TLDkVBd8UR82LvWYgarBL6SZbFzAcDebvjkVK9wqgn1kp5LhHtp5NpzbEXeLHJzRo5GBoWihsKndffjRSDk"
        }
    },
    "message": "You have successfully created your digital identity, firstName",
    "success": true
}
```

Comment: Ok, I just gave the did object the class Did? and I think it's working: `final Did? did;`. The only error that still excists is that weird catch return of an Object instead of an exception.

Comment: I think it's because some Parsing is not in the correct format that you are getting, isn't it?

Comment: I have added the response of the post request in my question and I'm also using Dio now but still can't put my response into the parser function `fromJson()`

Answer (score 0):

1. please use this [website](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) to convert you'r json to dart class.
2. please instead of :

   if (res.statusCode == 200) {
   final json = jsonDecode(res.toString());
   print(json);
   return Did.fromJson(json);
   }

use this :

```
if (res != null && res.statusCode == 200) {
    return Did.fromJson(response.data);
}
```

and believe me, use different state class for different situation, here for example you use same state for progress, error and loaded.

I hope i was able to help.